# MS Access SQL Insert Query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can seem to figure out the problem with this insert query.  I have some experience with SQL Server, but unfortunately am forced to use Access for this project (which I am new to).  At this point I have tried manually inserting into Access (which worked), and then copying the exact query into Visual Studio and I'm still getting an insert syntax error.  I am able to insert into other tables in this same test program, but I have not been able to get this query to work.

The table I am trying to insert into is set up as:

```
ID - Int Primary Key
time_series_id Int 
open decimal
high decimal
low decimal
close decimal
volume int
observation_date Date/Time
```

The manual query I tried is:

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO daily_prices (time_series_id, open, high, low, close, volume, observation_date) VALUES(13, 3036.75, 3045.72, 3023.27, 3027.52, 4894428992, '2013-09-24')";

command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The query was also originally formulated the following way:

```
queryString = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO daily_prices (time_series_id, open, high, low, close, volume, observation_date) VALUES ({0}, {1} ,{2} ,{3} ,{4} ,{5} ,'{6}')", newId, open, high, low, close, volume, date);
```

Any help would be appreciated here.  I'm sure it's a dumb mistake, but I am at a bit of a loss since I am able to execute the query in access, and then the same query fails in C#.

Comment: An Insert Syntax error, which is why I looked in the wrong place for so long I think.  I checked the Access reserved words, but not the SQL reserved words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word OPEN and CLOSE are reserved keywords for Jet-SQL (Jet 4.0). Use square brackets around them (or change the column name if possible)

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO daily_prices (time_series_id, [open], high, low, " + 
              "[close], volume, observation_date) VALUES " + 
              "(13, 3036.75, 3045.72, 3023.27, 3027.52, 4894428992, '2013-09-24')";
```

Comment: I looked up reserved words before posting this but must have been looking at the wrong list.  I knew it would be stupid.  Thanks Steve.

Comment: This is the list for [JET 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266), notice how these words are still reserved for [ACE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx), but you need to scroll down to see them. To me this is just bad impagination on MS side